# Django Registration Redux Registration form setting

Tags: python, django, registration

In Django Registration Redux, there are alternative registration forms that one can use. For Example, one can use RegistrationFormTermsOfService or RegistrationFormUniqueEmail in the registration.forms file. I read the code and figure that the way to do this is by setting a REGISTRATION_FORM variable in the settings.py file. In registration.views we see the following:

```
    REGISTRATION_FORM_PATH = getattr(settings, 'REGISTRATION_FORM','registration.forms.RegistrationForm')
    REGISTRATION_FORM = import_string( REGISTRATION_FORM_PATH )
```

However, when I do set the REGISTRATION_FORM in settings.py to 'registration.forms.RegistrationFormUniqueEmail', I still can't get the form for unique email. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I was completely confused by this problem (specifying reg_form in a subclassed RegistrationView and setting form_class both in that view and in urls.py had zero effect), until I stumbled upon this question - thanks for asking.

Answer (score 3):

Okay, so I figured this one out. Basically, in the version 1.1 of django registration redux, this option of setting which registration form in the setting was not available. The code I was looking at from github is the version 1.2 version. So if this happens to you, just install from github.

Comment: I got a compatible version using pip install on Ubuntu 14.04.